# Compile if condition from String Variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable

```
var condition = "if(2 > 5)";
```

And sometime it will be

```
var condition = "if(3>5 && 4<2){quantity = 45;} else quantity=60;";
```

How I can compile these conditions, as these are in string variable?

Comment: you need to seperate them in array and then work accordingly for each conditions

Comment: Have you looked into `eval()`?

Comment: eval() will make it but think twice before using it

Comment: i pass the complete condition to eval function which is If (22.13> 72) QTY=3; else QTY=2; but it gives me an error "Unexpected identifier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dangerous to use because it can allow most anything to be injected into your code, but `eval` is the right thing to use here, if you really do have to have string evaluated to code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

`eval(condition)`

Comment: how i can pass the complete condition like If (22.13> 72) QTY=3; else QTY=2

Comment: Thanks a lot, its compiled,

Comment: eval("if(2>4){ a=4} else {a=5}")